# Ffmpeg error in linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos

Any help on how I can solve this error: 
`ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a tad confused; what context is this in?

Comment: I try to run the command ffmpeg and get the error. But when I run 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/ffmpeg', everything works fine

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Basically, to find the file:

```
sudo find / -name libavdevice.so.52
```

For example, you've found this file in the `/usr/local/lib`. Next include that library into your library path. Add this to your `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

And finally after modifying this file run this:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Reference: [Ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.52: cannot open shared object file](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223015653/http://linuxserverguide.wordpress.com:80/2010/10/15/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libavdevice-so-52-cannot-open-shared-object-file/)

Comment: Was it that `find` turned up with nothing, or was it that after reloading the config, it didn't work?

Comment: thank you, I visited the url you put up there, and I was able to solve the error. Thanks

Comment: it worked when I just added /usr/local/lib/ at the end of /etc/ld.so.conf. "include" keyword wasn't working.

Comment: I tried this with libopenh264.so.5 but it didn't work

Comment: Some users may get nothing in `find`, check the file name once again and do not just copy paste. ffmpeg maybe raising error for another file. ex. `libavdevice.so.59` then just modify name in search and rest works.