# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I am using ffmpeg and getting this error

`ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have already checked if the library exists and it does. I added it to /etc/ld.so.conf as mentioned in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901706/ffmpeg-error-in-linux) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I compiled it

Comment: How did you compile it? Provide the link if you followed instructions from a site.

Comment: I followed this link http://embedonix.com/articles/linux/installing-ffmpeg-from-source-on-ubuntu-14-0-4/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I faced this error when I run ffmpeg 4.2.2 under python 3.8 environment.

The root cause is that `libopen264.so` from python 3.8 is too new for ffmpeg 4.2.2.
I can find
`libopen264.so.6` under the `~/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/` (py38 is my conda virtual environment), but we only need an older version `libopen264.so.5`.

To solve the problem, I just make a softlink from my existing anaconda environment (python 3.7) as follows - and it works.

`ln -s ~/anaconda3/lib/libopenh264.so ~/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/libopenh264.so.5`

Comment: it helped me, but with a difference. my base env didn't contained libopenh264.so  . My target env contained one that i renamed it to libopenh264.so.5 and the problem solved.

Answer (score 26):

Another approach that seemed easier and worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.8 was just calling:

```
conda update ffmpeg
```

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511660/11700877).

Comment: This helped me. A much easier solution than others. I would suggest people to try this out and see if it works.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this by:

- Downloading the [openh264 binary from GitHub](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases/tag/v2.1.1)
- Copying/renaming the binary to my conda env, e.g. `~/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/libopenh264.so.5` where `py38` is the env name

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: this worked!

I used command 

`cp libopenh264-2.1.0-linux64.5.so ~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/libopenh264.so.5`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, to fix it I removed all installs of ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
```

After doing this, the output was still the same, `which ffmpeg` showed me I was using the one from anaconda, so I removed that one (renamed it)

Then I could do a clean install and now it works again:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: I removed them, but the problem is still existing

Comment: I have the following error "Some packages cannot be installed. This can mean that you asked for the impossible, or else, if you use the unstable distribution, which some packages have not yet have been created or have not left Incoming." with a list of packages that will not be installed

Comment: I am also having this issue but on Debian 10.

Answer (score 2):

I copy `~/anaconda3/lib/libopenh264.so`, paste to the same folder and rename it to `libopenh264.so.5`. And it works.

Comment: Doing `ln -s ~/anaconda3/lib/libopenh264.so ~/anaconda3/lib/libopenh264.so.5` has the same effect.

Comment: I totally just changed the name in my install and it seems to have worked so far :/

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue with system-installed `ffmpeg`, and pip-installed `ffmpeg-python` within a conda environment.

The work-around for me was uninstalling the system ffmpeg and installing as [ffmpeg as a conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ffmpeg) within my conda environment:

```
# Uninstall ffmpeg system install (assumes Ubuntu)
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg -y
sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg -y

# Install ffmpeg in conda env
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I did what Synthesis did, that is

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
```

However, I removed the Anaconda ffmpeg module

```
conda remove ffmpeg
```

The clean install then did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

My error don't have "ffmpeg".But it also says there is no libopenh264.so.5 here.
I have solved it. The reason is that I should use `pip install opencv-python` to install these files

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just had to deactivate my conda environment to make it work!

`conda deactivate`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all installed `ffmpeg`:

```bash
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
```

2. Delete the the Anaconda `ffmpeg` module from your environment:

```bash
conda remove ffmpeg
```

3. Reinstall `ffmpeg`:

```bash
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```