# FFMPEG 4.2.4, Python 3.9: "ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg 4.2.4 and Python 3.9

Currently getting error:
`ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Tried the solutions from these links but they didn't work:
[ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213783/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libopenh264-so-5)
[Ffmpeg error in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901706/ffmpeg-error-in-linux)

If anyone has any idea how to fix it, or needs any more information, please let me know.

---

Edit: I've noticed that it's been over a year later since I created this post and it's still getting replies - I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Wilann/a187a3aebc19914605bc6a7bd90b7986) explaining another way I overcame a similar issue

Basically, I uninstalled conda's version of `ffmpeg` (in the environment that's having issues) using `conda uninstall ffmpeg --force` and (for Ubuntu), update the system wide version (I think this is what it's called) with `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 7):

Figured out you can `conda update ffmpeg`, even though you can't install it with conda...
Completely fixed the issue. Posting this incase someone else has the same problem.
Note: I got (the faulty) ffmpeg from downloading PyTorch with the command via the official site.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Though I should note my ffmpeg wasn't faulty, just old, and I'd upgraded various things to accommodate a new GPU so it (apparently) needed some upgrading as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like Wilan, my issue stemmed from getting ffmpeg with PyTorch. `conda update ffmpeg` did not work for me, but `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg` (specifying the conda-forge channel) fixed my issue.